# T SQL if column exists then (if it has value X then (

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to perform the following logical clause:

If column is present and it has certain value then do something. 
If not, then do something else.

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name      = N'legacyoptions'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'config '))
BEGIN
    if ( select legacyoptions from config)=1 
        begin 
            Do stuff when legacy=1
        end
        else begin
            Do stuff when legacy !=1 
        END 
else 
begin
  do stuff when legacy is not present
end
```

However, this does not work in case `legacyoptions` is not present

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the way to go.

Comment: Your sql seems fine to me. what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - if there is no column called `legacyoptions` in the `config` table, then this entire batch will fail to *compile*. So it never gets a chance to run the test to see if the column exists and then run the `SELECT` statement that queries that column.

Comment: @damien correct, of course... I don't know how I've missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way using TRY CATCH block and a dynamic SQL so this block of code will be compiled without table `config` and/or `legacyoptions`field in the database.

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @legacyoptions int;  
    EXECUTE sp_executesql N'select TOP 1 @legacyoptions=legacyoptions from config', 
                          N'@legacyoptions int OUTPUT', 
                          @legacyoptions OUTPUT;
    if @legacyoptions=1 
        begin 
          -- Do stuff when legacy=1
        end
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
          -- Do stuff when legacy !=1 
        END   
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
     -- do stuff when legacy is not present
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :(i guess you are leaving an end of if)

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name      = N'legacyoptions'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'config '))
BEGIN
    if ( select legacyoptions from config)=1 
        begin 
            Do stuff when legacy=1
        end
        else begin
            Do stuff when legacy !=1 
        END 
end
else 
begin
  do stuff when legacy is not present
end
```

Comment: Sorry, this returns "Invalid column name 'legacyoptions'." when running on DB where legacyOptions column is missing.  If I comment the second if out it works fine, but this is the issue itself.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but seems stupid to me. 


`IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM sys.columns  WHERE Name = N'legacyoptions' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'config '))
BEGIN
exec('
    if (select legacyoptions from config)=1
        begin
            print ''Config==1''
        end
        else
        begin
            print ''Config!=1''
        end
     ')
end
else
begin
    print 'no legacy'
end`

Comment: Why does it seem stupid to you? Are you familiar with other programming languages? The original code is similar to, in another language, trying to write a method that first uses reflection/introspection to determine whether a particular type contains a particular method, and then calls that method on an instance of the type - and it failed for the same reason - that it couldn't even *compile* the code, so it never had the opportunity to perform its runtime check.